# Find complexity of iterative algorithm with i and j

Tags: algorithm, while-loop, complexity-theory

[Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NcPvK.png)

[image]

Hi guys! I am trying to find the complexity of the following algorithm.

Currently, what I've done is the following - I've realised that:

- i increases n times
- i increases whenever j > i^2

soo:
j > 1
j > 4
...
j > n^2

And I'm thinking that maybe the complexity of the algorithm is

[My solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pG8ED.png)
[image]

Thanks all!

Comment: do you mean i increases when j<i^2?

Comment: I've just edited my question, you can now see the problem snippet.

Comment: What notation shall be used? Loop iterations, instructions executed, O(N), anything else? The answer you provided suggests loop iterations.

Comment: Your approach is correct and hence, complexity is O(n^3)

Comment: O(n) (or theta)
so in my case I think it's n^3